# How to concatenate and transfer bytes from unsigned char[10] to char[10]?

Tags: c

I have an unsigned char with byte values. I defined a loop that increments the indices of the array and takes its bytes. I'm trying to pass the values ​​from unsigned char to char and concatenate each value one at a time and go displaying the result in the terminal. How can I convert from unsigned char to char in c?

**What I tried to do:**

- Use strcmp(s1, s2):
- Used strcat(s1, s2):

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char byte_loop[10] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x10};
    char text_concat[10];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        text_concat[i] = byte_loop[i];
        //Display the result of the string as the bytes are concatenated
        printf("Texto Concatenado: %s", text_concat);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to convert? What output do you expect since those are all generally unprintable characters? `i <= 10` goes one past the end of the array, and `printf` requires a 0 terminated string which you're not providing.

Comment: `i <= 10;` --> `i < 10;`

Comment: `char text_concat[10];` --> `char text_concat[10] = { 0 };`

Comment: if you really want to make those values printable, you can add 0x30 to each of them (0x31 is ascii code for 1, 0x32 is ascii code for 2 and so on) https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html

Comment: BUT... even after fixing the two issues above, you still wont get any nice print as 1,  2, 3, ... does print well. For fun try: `text_concat[i] = byte_loop[i];` --> `text_concat[i] = '0' + byte_loop[i];`

Comment: `printf`'s `%s` specifier requires the corresponding argument to be null terminated unless a precision has been specified, e.g. `printf("%.10s", text_concat);`. Those character values are not ASCII printable characters though.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/r39uCX

Comment: I just want to transfer the content from byte loop[10] to text_concat[10].

Comment: You can't use `str...` functions unless you are dealing with actual strings. Which you aren't in this case, you are dealing with raw data. So what are you actually asking here, how to convert raw data to a string format?

Comment: Please,  how to convert raw data to a string format?

Comment: What character do you expect for example from the byte value 0x01?

Comment: Char in C is represented by its integer "code" and, stored as an 8-bit number (really a byte). Assuming you have an array of characters in the 7-bit ASCII range (`0x00`-`0x7F`), e.g `unsigned char x[] = {0x53,0x74,0x61,0x63,0x6B,0x20,0x4F,0x76,0x65,0x72,0x66,0x6C,0x6F,0x77};` (not null terminated) you can print them using a precision specifier e.g. `printf("Unsigned value: %.14s", x);`